# Resetting Xcode's device/version list to run

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I want to test/run my app on different iOS versions in Xcode, but somehow I can't see any option to change iOS simulator version (I have both 6 and 7 SDK/Simulator installed) in run targets. I'm also seeing all of my attached devices twice (I have only ONE iPod, but when I connect something else, they all display twice):

[image]

There's probably a bug with the device list of Xcode. How can I reset this list? I've tried resetting the scheme, but scheme is project related anyway. The problem occurs in all projects, not only a single project.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to install the 6.1 Simulator.
After that, you can choose which simulator version to use:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem. I was on the "Latest iOS SDK" which was 7.1 SDK (I also have XCode 5.1DP installed). I've changed the base SDK to 7.0 and I am again able to choose. I still have two entries for each physical device but I can live with that.